# Possibility of Race Condition on using Java Locks

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-8, thread-safety

I've written a Java class and someone has reviewed the code and insisted that there could be a race condition in method `calculate`. Here's a simplified version of the class code:

```
public class MyClass {
    private List<Integer> list;
    private final ReadWriteLock lock;

    public MyClass() {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    }

    public void add(Integer integer) {
        lock.writeLock().lock();
        try {
            list.add(integer);
        } finally {
            lock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }

    public void deleteAll() {
        lock.writeLock().lock();
        try {
            list.clear();
        } finally {
            lock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }

    public Integer calculate() {
        List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>();
        Integer result = 0;

        lock.readLock().lock();
        try {
            list.forEach(integer -> {
                // calculation logic that reads values from 'list' and adds only a subset of elements from 'list' in 'newList'
            });
        } finally {
            lock.readLock().unlock();
        }

        setList(newList);
        return result;
    }

    private void setList(List<Integer> newList) {
        lock.writeLock().lock();
        try {
            list = newList;
        } finally {
            lock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Now my question is:

Can a race condition really happen in this method, and if so how can I solve it (either using locks or using any other method to make the class thread safe)?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: did reviewer explain why he thinks there is a race condition?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: I said (and this is my general assumption) that if Java locks work properly as expected, so there shouldn't be a race condition in the method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a time gap between creation of `newList` and call to `setList(newList)`. We may assume this time gap is arbitrary long, and everything can happen when it lasts, e.g. another thread adds an object which must be retained, but it will be lost when  call to `setList(newList)` removes `list` with that new object.

In fact, the method `calculate` is modifying and should do all the work under write lock.

Comment: So you mean the problem is the following:

-> Thread1 starts executing method `calculate`

-> Thread2 starts executing method `calculate`

-> Thread1 adds some objects to "its" `newList` and calls `setList` to modify `list` while Thread2 is still calculating and adding objects to "its `newList`

-> Eventually Thread2 finishes and calls `setList` which overwrites what was added by Thread1.

Do you mean this is the race condition scenario?

Comment: @Mis94 No.  Thread1 starts executing method calculate -> Thread2 starts executing method add and waits for lock -> Thread1 finished to collect "its" newList and releases readLock -> Thread2 aquires writeLock and adds its object to  MyClass.list -> Thread1 calls setList and replaces MyClass.list, wiping out the object added by Thread2.

Comment: It should be emphasized that the problematic time gap exists between `lock.readLock().unlock();` and `lock.writeLock().lock();`; the other artifacts of the code structure are irrelevant. Besides the possibility of a thread calling `add` or `deleteAll` in-between, there can be an arbitrary number of threads executing `calculate()` itself, as it only has a read lock while calculating the new list state.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify the above ... the statement

`List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>();`

... instantiates a data-structure (`list` ...) that will subsequently be used within the block of code that is intended to be protected by `lock.readLock().lock();`, but is not contained within it.  Therefore it is not protected.

To remedy the problem, the declaration of `newList` should not include initialization.  Nothing which affects the presumed value of this variable should exist outside of the lock-protected block.

Comment: `newList` is a local variable inside `calculate` method and is not an instance field in the class (like `list`), why should it be protected. Isn't each thread executing the method has its "own" `newList` variable?

Comment: @Mis94 you are right, `newList` is a local variable and it points to a newly created object not seen by any other thread, hence, doesn’t need any protection.